# Is there any way to read a macro-enabled workbook in VBA and process its data without terminating the desired VBA program and executing its macros?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently converting the files manually to .xlsx by "saving as" the .xlsm file to .xlsx, and overriding the objections, but there do not need to be many of these to make doing the job manually impractical. if I try to open an .xlsm file in VBA it terminates the current (desired) program and switches to the program in the .xlsm file I am trying read as data.
This process used to work with Excel 2016 (or 2012, I can't recall which I was using at the time, about a year ago). I am currently using Excel 2021.

Comment: Set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before you open the file - this prevents that any autostart macros are executed. Don't forget to set it back to True when you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Application.AutomationSecurity` - see  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.automationsecurity

Seems like it's intended for your specific use case.

Example from that link:

```vb
Sub Security() 
    Dim secAutomation As MsoAutomationSecurity 
 
    secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity  'capture current setting
 
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
 
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show  'open a file
 
    Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation  'restore original setting
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams. **That is exactly what I wanted.** I just included the use of DisplayAlerts and the whole conversion went smoothly.